# How get OSX Lion to save Modifier Key Settings (i.e. swap Ctrl and Cmd)

Tags: keyboard, osx-lion

I use Lion at work with an MS Natural Ergonomic Keyboard 4000.  Every single time I log in I have to go into settings and swap the command and control keys.  This is really annoying.  Is there a way to get these settings to stick?

Beyond that, I'd also like to remap a few other keys and I'm interested in tools for doing that.  I think I need to work out the first issue first though.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: I'm having this same problem on Mavericks now too -- every time my MBP goes to sleep or reboots, it "forgets" that I had swapped Modifier Keys!

Answer (score 0):

Well i use an apple keyboard, so i have no idea why the switching of cmd & ctrl doesn't stick.

But you might have better luck trying [KeyRemap4Macbook](http://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/), which contrary to it's name works with all keyboards on any mac. *Especially* PC keyboards. Really designed for these sort of things.

For changing the standard keys i use [Ukelele](http://scripts.sil.org/cms/scripts/page.php?site_id=nrsi&id=ukelele) which has a far better GUI and produces a standard keylayout xml OSX understands natively.